# Pip install failure for tensorflow-gpu - OSError: raw write() returned invalid length

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

When installing tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0 using pip in Windows 10 (Python 3.5), I get the following strange error. Very interestingly, each time I run

```
pip.exe install tensorflow-gpu
```

it downloads a small but seemingly random part of the package, then raises the following exception:

```
(C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35) E:\Data\ownCloud\Work\CoronaryML>pip.exe install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (67.6MB)
Exception:                              | 266kB 797kB/s eta 0:01:25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
_download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 603, in _download_url
hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 141, in iter
self.next(n)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.py", line 73, in next
self.update()
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\bar.py", line 41, in update
self.writeln(line)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\helpers.py", line 67, in writeln
self.clearln()
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\helpers.py", line 63, in clearln
print('\r\x1b[K', end='', file=self.file)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 166, in write_and_convert
self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, start)
  File "C:\Users\carth\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
OSError: raw write() returned invalid length 2 (should have been between 0 and 1)
```

I tried turning off my antivirus, in case that was killing it, but it didn't help.

In the end, I managed to install it by downloading the .whl from PyPI manually, then running `pip.exe install path/to/.whl`, but I'd like to understand what caused the original failure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been documented here, you can update to python 3.6 or install and enable the win_unicode_console package to solve it

https://bugs.python.org/issue32245

Comment: but doesn't the latest tensorflow build only support 3.5? I'm sure I read that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `cmd` with administrator rights to run the command：
`pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu -i https://pypi.tuna.
tsinghua.edu.cn/simple`